# Can an active session in oracle be dead?

Tags: oracle, session

I have a time consuming query which populates a materialized view.  It has been running for 18 hours - which was not expected.

```
SELECT STATUS
FROM V$SESSION
WHERE SID=194;
```

The above query shows the session as 'ACTIVE'.  I was wondering if that is sufficient proof that the query is still running and whether there is any other way to double check that the session is not dead.

***UPDATE***

The session was not dead; but there was a constant wait:

```
 SQL*Net more data from dblink
```

I used sql trace as suggested by Phil to reach this conclusion.

Comment: What does `v$session_longops` say? you can use `sofar/totalwork` to see what percentage done it is. If that draws a blank, trace the session and see if anything appears in the trace file

Comment: 'v$session_longops' gives blank.  Thanks for the tip; I will have a look into tracing the session.

Comment: I will have to rerun the query to run the trace on it; which is a bit inconvenient in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should query 
[V$SESSION_WAIT](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-4EDAB293-F3FC-40FE-BC75-4FEE6A4D7705.htm#REFRN30229)
to see what your statement is doing. A short description of the wait events can be found in ["Part IV Appendixes", "C Oracle Wait Events" of the "Database Reference"](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/toc.htm)